# input type=number in BB10 with decimal point on virtual keyboard doen't working

Tags: html, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I was unable to find the solution to this problem:

I use one  in a webworks app. It's supose that this input will accept integers and float numbers.

The problem is: When I insert some data, for example 3.1415 the device removes the dot and inserts 31415.

I'm not using the input types inside a form so the "novalidate" option isn't possible.

I tried a lot of stuff to fix the problem. Any Idea?

Possible solutions(tricks):
- Use type = text and force the keyboard layout to be the numeric one.
- Disable the validation to this input (and no others).

Do you know how to do that? Do you know other solutions?

Regards. Pablo.

Comment: What OS version are you testing this on (ie 10.0, 10.1, 10.2) ?

Comment: Im using the version 10.1.0.4181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know bug in Blackberry 10.

There are posts about it in their support forum, [here is a link to one of them](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/input-type-number-in-BB10-without-decimal-point-on-virtual/td-p/2025997).

The only real way around it is to use a standard text input and validate the content yourself until this bug is fixed.

Comment: And what about the keyboard map?, how can I force it to be the numeric one?

Comment: You could try [-wap-input-format](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2218-how-to-validate-text-for-mobile/) in your CSS and/or [the pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on an internal build (10.2.1.x) and it is working prefect for me although I'm unable to track down a specific OS build number where the fix was implemented.